# How to import extension along with files in visual studio code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code

Development using nodejs for running **(--experimental-modules)**

Current visual studio code intelligence import as below

> import config from "./config";

but required as below

> import config from "./config.js";

Without .js getting error as below

```
internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:61
  let url = moduleWrapResolve(specifier, parentURL);
            ^

Error: Cannot find module C:\Uday\Projects\practice-server\config imported from C:\Uday\Projects\practice-server\index.js
    at Loader.defaultResolve [as _resolve] (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:61:13)
    at Loader.resolve (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:85:40)
    at Loader.getModuleJob (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:191:28)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:42:40)
    at link (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:41:36) {
  code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
}
```

So i need visual studio code intelligence for importing with extension??

```
//index.js
import express from "express";
import config from "./config.js";



const api_app = express();
const api_port = config.api_port
api_app.listen(api_port, () => {
    console.log(`Practice Server started on ${api_port}`);
});

//package.json
{
  "name": "practice-server",
  "type": "module",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1"
  }
}

//config.js
let config = function () { };

config.api_port = 6000;


export default config;
```

Comment: Can you please share your code with more details ?

Comment: update the question

Answer (score 16):

In the global  settings (or the project settings), add the following configuration:

```js
  // Preferred path ending for auto imports.
  //  - auto: Use project settings to select a default.
  //  - minimal: Shorten `./component/index.js` to `./component`.
  //  - index: Shorten `./component/index.js` to `./component/index`
  //  - js: Do not shorten path endings; include the `.js` extension.

  "javascript.preferences.importModuleSpecifierEnding": "js",
```

Note that at the moment this only works for **auto imports** (i.e via intellisense when referencing an export of another file and VSCode imports it automatically). It does not work with with autosuggest when typing the import statement manually.

Comment: Adding `typescript.preferences.importModuleSpecifierEnding": "js"` may also be required as well.

Answer (score 0):

I always used my config.js like this this. May be it can help you.

```
const config = require('./config');
```

//Now access value from config

```
const sys_dbconfig = config_data['sys_database'];
const user = configdata['system_admin_name'];
```

Here is my config.js

```
var config = {
"sys_database": {
    "user": 'postgres',
    "host": 'localhost',
    "database": 'postgres',
    "password": 'postgres',
    "port": "5432"
},
"system_admin_name": "system",
"url":"http://xxx.xx.x.xxx:3000/wscalc1?wsdl"
}

module.exports = config;
```

Comment: I need for es6 coding not node.js