# How to have top level await in typescript (switch from commonjs to esnext) without having to change all imports to have .js ending

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, tsc

I would like to have top level await in my typescript nodejs project.

My tsconfig used to look like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2017",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es6",
      "es2017",
      "esnext.asynciterable"
    ],
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
#### other stuff which I think is not relevant removed ####
```

And I now switched it to

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es6",
      "es2017",
      "esnext.asynciterable"
    ],
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
#### other stuff which I think is not relevant removed ####
```

I have also added `"type": "module"` to my package.json. Indeed I now have the ability to do top level awaits however

1. I need to change every import to add the .js file extension
2. For folders where I added an index.ts to export all the modules I could previously just import the folder name. Now I need to import foldername/index.js
3. When I auto add an import with vscode it adds it without the .js

The way it is with commonjs is so elegant - can I have the same behaviour with esnext or keep it some other way while gaining top-level await?

Comment: see if [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61645194/5058682) helps you for your 2nd and 3rd point.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of what your tsconfig.json file might look like:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es6",
      "es2017",
      "esnext.asynciterable"
    ],
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true
    },
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if that is an option, but i think the easiest approach would be, to wrap the entrance of your application into some kind of `main()` function that is async and execute that function. Inside this function, you can use await like you want.